# Proving with functions

Tags: functions, proof-verification

If f and g are functions such that f ◦ (f ◦ g) = f ◦ (g ◦ f), then f = g.

Prove it or find a counter example for this statement.
So I start by going like this

Suppose f(x) = x − 2 and g(x) = x^2

(f ◦ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(x^2) = x^2 - 2
(g ◦ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(x-2) = (x-2)^2

But I wasn't sure how to carry that on, any advice would be great.

Comment: Take $f \equiv 1$ and $g$ to be any other function.

Comment: Suppose f = 0 and g = 1 (constant functions).

Comment: so I suppose f.= 0 and f= 1 instead of x - 2 and x ^2 ?

Comment: Try the compositions $f \circ (f \circ g)$ and  $f \circ (g \circ f)$ using $f=0$ and $g=1$.

Comment: Hint: It is well-known that $f\circ g\ne g\circ f$ in general. If we set $h:=f\circ g,h'=g\circ f$, these functions are both independent of $f$ and there is little reason that $f\circ h=f\circ h'$. So you'd better start by looking for a counterexample.

Comment: Taking g=x and f be any other function would also work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a fundamental misconception about proof and disproof.

To prove the statement

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f) \implies f = g$$

you would have to show that *all* pairs of functions $(f,g)$ satisfying

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f)$$

must be such that $f=g$.

So one example couldn't be used to *prove* the statement.

On the other hand, if you can find even *one* pair $(f,g)$ with $f \ne g$ such that

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f)$$

you would have a counterexample, which would thereby *disprove* the statement.

You considered the functions
\begin{align*}
&f(x) = x-2\\[4pt]
&g(x) = x^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Since that's just one example, it couldn't be used to prove the given statement.

But perhaps it could be used for a disproof?

If so, the pair $(f,g)$ would have to satisfy

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f)$$

Let's check . . .

\begin{align*}
(f \circ (f \circ g))(x) &= f(f(g(x)))\\[4pt]
&=f(f(x^2))\\[4pt]
&=f(x^2-2)\\[4pt]
&=x^2-4\\[12pt]
(f \circ (g \circ f))(x) &= f(g(f(x)))\\[4pt]
&=f(g(x-2))\\[4pt]
&=f((x-2)^2)\\[4pt]
&=(x-2)^2-2\\[4pt]
&=x^2-4x+2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Since the pair $(f,g)$ doesn't satisfy

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f)$$

that pair doesn't yield a counterexample.

In abstract form, to disprove a statement of the form
$$\text{if $P$, then $Q$}$$
you would need to produce an example for which $P$ is true, but $Q$ is false.

For this question, $P$ is the statement

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f)$$

and $Q$ is the statement

$$f = g$$

For your example pair $(f,g)$, the statements $P$ and $Q$ are *both* false, so that pair doesn't yield a counterexample (to "if $P$ then $Q$").

As was suggested in the comments, if you let $f$ be any constant function, then

$$f \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ (g \circ f)$$

is automatically true, hence to get a counterexample, take any pair $(f,g)$, where $f$ is a constant function, and $g$ is any function other than $f$.

Comment: Thanks ! I just don't understand how to do all that with regular numbers only done It using "x" but ill give it a crack :)

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is a constant function, say $f(x)=3$. What would be the value of $f(5)$? What about $f(g(x))$ where, say $g(x)  = x^2 - x$?

Comment: "that pair doesn't yield a counterexample": are you sure ? This is the key sentence in your explanation.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: A counterexample to "if $P$ then $Q$" must have $P$ true and $Q$ false. For the OP's attempted counterexample using $f=x-2,\;g=x^2$, the statements $P,Q$ are both false.

Comment: $f:=x^2,g:=x-2$ is clearly a counterexample, full stop.

Comment: The OP's example had $f=x-2$ and $g=x^2$. As I showed in my answer, that pair fails to satisfy the hypothesis.